# How to get Facebook user email using Parse.com login

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com SDK.

I have a login into Facebook using parse SDK and I need to get the logged in user's mail address. How can I do it?

P.S. Currently I'm not make any use with Facebook official login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27142277/5138257) answer.

To set profile, add this to your code:

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```